# Access a variable from a class from different file

Tags: python, class

I have two files a.py and b.py 
In b.py there is class defined as follow:

```
class ii(ldata) ..... 
      self.mn()

      def mn(self) .... 
          return t1,t2
```

I want the values of `t1` and `t2` in a.py 
In file a.py I have imported b

```
from b import ii 
t1,t2=ii()
```

But I get an error. `class ii has no attribute 't1'`

Can anyone let me know how to access the value `t1` and `t2` in a.py

Comment: You probably need `return self.t1, self.t2`, for the return value of `mm()`

Comment: can you show a little more code, including imports with a and b? Is this code snippet from a.py or b.py? But I am currently siding with @GWW

Comment: I've tried to fix the formatting of your code, but I'm afraid the `self.mn()` call in `ii` doesn't make any sense the way it is now. Can you please update the question with somewhat more complete code? Its very hard to guess what's going on with what you've shown.

Comment: That code would not give that error.

Comment: The code is too big cannot put here as it states too long while uploading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function `mn` from the class `ii` to be able to set the variables `t1 and t2`. So you have to do something like:

```
import b
ii iclass
t1,t2 = iclass.mn()
```

Hope this gives you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question where `t1` and `t2` are defined. However, after you import `b` with

```
import b
```

there are three ways in which `a.py` could see `t1` (and `t2`, by analogy):

1. `b.t1` - if `t1` is defined as a module-level global, it exists directly in `b.py`'s global namespace.
2. `b.ii.t1` - if `t1` is defined at the class level inside `ii`, it is a class variable.
3. `inst = b.ii(); inst.t1` - `t1` is defined as an instance variable for instances of the class `b.ii`

Otherwise, `t1` would appear to be a local variable to some function or method defined in `b.py`, and is not visible outside that scope.